# Read Env Vars from a File in AWS Elastic Beanstalk during deployment

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, parameters, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, getparameter

We traditionally stored our env vars in Environment->Configuration->Software in Elastic Beanstalk console and access it in our NodeJS app by typing process.env.VariableName. There's a hard limit for the number of vars stored there, so we moved our variables to AWS Parameter Store.

I have a .ebextention script that downloads the parameters from the parameter store and saves them to a file in /home/ec2-user directory named .env.local, but I can't reference them in the app with process.env.

.ebextention script:

```
commands:
  01_command2:
    command: aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path /latest/ --recursive --with-decryption --output text --query "Parameters[].[Name,Value]" --region us-west-2 | sed -E 's#latest/([^[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]*#export \1=#' > /home/ec2-user/.env.local
```

How can I access these vars in NodeJS without modifying the way that we correctly use env vars (process.env.VarName)?